# Storing a series of numbers with fixed minimum and maximum, efficiently

Tags: encoding, binary, compression, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic

I have a series of numbers, always starting from 64 and ending at 8. The sequence of numbers could be 64, 63, 62, 56, 50, 30, 29, 28, 27, 8. It can also be 64, 55, 27, 26, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 9, 8, and many other types.

There are some fixed parameters in my sequence:
- For each 8-bytes of data in a file, there is one sequence of numbers. So if a file is 8 KB, there are approximately 1,000 of these sequences (of course with some frequencies and some unique sequences within them).
- The numbers are always descending,
- The maximum number is 64 and the minimum number is 8, in all sequences,
- There's no fixed number of decimals in the sequence. Sometimes it can consist of all numbers from 64 to 8, sometimes 10 numbers, sometimes 30 numbers, and sometimes more or less.

I want to be able to save these numbers in less than 56 bits, more less than that. For example, if I want to assign a single bit for each number, and turn a bit on (1) when each number is present in the sequence, and turn it off (0) when a number is not present in the sequence, there will normally be 56 bits of data to be saved in my file.

Regarding the fact that all the file is composed of these numbers between 64 and 8, is there any way that I can efficiently store the sequences in a smaller file?

Comment: If 64 and 8 are always included, then you need only 55 bits (there are only 55 distinct integers in the interval [9,63]). | Thinking about it, the result is basically like delta coding, with the residuals encoded in variable length code -- `n-1` zeros terminated by a one. | If all the sequences are equally probable and independent, then on average you won't do better. (There are 2^55 possible sequences (the number of k-combinations for all k) ; recall pigeonhole principle)

Comment: Thanks @DanMašek. That's right about the equal probabilities. However, there's fortunately about 50% of the file (file is consisted of those series of numbers, 55 bits as you put it), can be described using only a certain number of combinations. I need to have a binary string that can efficiently show the combination of series. Not all the combinations are going to be used, and some of the combinations are more frequently used than the other ones.